# Is there an alternative to the project Mozilla byob?

Tags: firefox, browser, mozilla

I want to ask you if there is an alternative to the project of [Mozilla byob](http://byob.mozilla.com/) (build your own browser, shut down recently).

If someone made it something similar maybe with Firefox or another browser.

Comment: basically all the major web browser are open source or they have a big part of their code base released to the public, only Opera is closed source. Chrome offers Chromium as related opensource project, Firefox is open source, the webkit engine is opensource, you have a lot of options if you are a programmer.

Comment: @Ken: "basically all" as in "two out of five"? :) Only Firefox and Chrome are open source whereas Internet Explorer, Opera and Safari are not (WebKit engine doesn't count, Safari itself is still closed source). Anyway, changing browser source code and recompiling/repackaging it (what about updates?) is definitely not a recommendable solution.

Comment: @WladimirPalant safari uses webkit, Internet Explorer ... let's exclude it. If you want to it's not that hard to assembly a web browser from the scratch with free software.

Comment: @Ken: Feel free to compile Safari (*not* its rendering engine) from source - once you succeed doing that let me know. The question is about *customizing* a browser, not about building a new one from existing blocks (and reimplementing the entire UI).

Answer (score 0):

There is the [CCK Wizard](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cck/) that allows various Firefox customizations. You don't get an actual Firefox build but an extension. One way to deploy that extension on a machine would be [adding it to the Windows registry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Adding_Extensions_using_the_Windows_Registry) which will automatically install it into all Firefox profiles on the particular machine. One could also modify a Firefox installer to include that extension but that is somewhat more complicated.